# CodeWars Javascript Challenge: Are they the "same"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

The Kata: [link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/550498447451fbbd7600041c/train/javascript)

My solution:

```
function comp(array1, array2) {
    let result;
    if (Array.isArray(array1) && Array.isArray(array2) && array1.length && array2.length) {
        result = true;
        const squares = array2.map(e => Math.sqrt(e));
        squares.forEach((e) => {
            if (array1.includes(e)) return;
            result = false;
        });
    } else {
        result = false
    }
    return result;
}
```

**I don't want another solution.** I want to figure out why mine doesn't pass in all of the tests. (Fails on two tests but I can't see which)

I suspect the test expects `true` if both arrays are `[]`. But the Kata's description says otherwise:

> If a or b are nil (or null or None), the problem doesn't make sense so return false.

Help would be appreciated.

---

**Working Solution Based off of the answers:**

```
function comp(array1, array2) {
    let result;
    if (Array.isArray(array1) && Array.isArray(array2)) {
        result = true;
        const sortedArray1 = array1.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        const squares = array2.map(e => Math.sqrt(e)).sort((a, b) => a - b);
        squares.forEach((e, i) => {
            if (sortedArray1[i] === e) return;
            result = false;
        });
    } else {
        result = false
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The description you provide from the kata talks of `null` values, whereas your suspicion is of empty arrays.  The two are not the same.  Did you test your suspicion?

Comment: Seems to me that `nil` or `null` are different from `[]`.

Comment: If I remove  `&& array1.length && array2.length` from the `if` statement it passes on one more test. I think that my suspicion was correct but it still fails on one test. I'll play around with it assuming it expects true for empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, some cheating workarounds but your code fails here:
[image]
That's why after removing two `.length` you pass one more test.

Next one is
[image]
After `.sqrt` array2 you get `2, 3, 3` that's why you return true, but it's false. That answer will be enough to help you solve this kata.

Btw.

> I suspect the test expects true if both arrays are []. But the Kata's
>   description says otherwise:

Kata's description:

> a or b might be [] (all languages except R, Shell).
>   : - D

P.S. I know for some people checking arguments maybe treated as cheating, I just do it for educational purposes. Black boxes are not always enough to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I never thought about logging the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

if there is more then one number the same, but different count here and there, it will return true in your code, since it's `includes` in both arrays. you should sort it and iterate by index for compare, in order to make sure each item in the array used only once.

Here is what works for me:

```
function comp(array1, array2){
  if(!array1 || !array2) return false;
  array1 = array1.map(t => t**2).sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  array2 = array2.sort((a,b)=>a-b);

  for(let i=0;i<array1.length;i++){if(array1[i] !== array2[i])return false}
  return true;
}
```

sure youcan understand the idea and just make some twick in your existing code